# How to know what's coming from push notification in iOS?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I can't NSLog as simulator doesn't support push notification. How I can view the data coming from push notification and what's in that launchOption dictionary?

Comment: you need to run in real device.

Comment: You can do what you want on iOS device, and debug as much as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you want real devices to check push notification.

There is one method to check content of push notification in ios

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
        NsLog("%@",userInfo);//In the userinfo you will get the content of push notification.
}
```

May be it will help you.